# From one matrix form to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix equation, which translates to the form below.

$$\Phi(t)=\left[\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{rr}-2 & 0 \\ 1 & -1\end{array}\right] t+\left[\begin{array}{rr}4 & 0 \\ -3 & 1\end{array}\right] \frac{t^{2}}{2 !}+\left[\begin{array}{rr}-8 & 0 \\ 7 & -1\end{array}\right] \frac{t^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots=$$

$$=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1-2 t+\frac{4 t^{2}}{2 !}-\frac{8 t^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots & 0 \\ 0+t-\frac{3 t^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{7 t^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots & 1-t+\frac{t^{2}}{2 !}-\frac{t^{3}}{3 !}+\ldots\end{array}\right]$$

What kind of operations led me from the first form to the second form?

Comment: The operation is summing a series.

Comment: Sum the four components separately - you are summing 4 different series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only operations applied here are multiplying a matrix by a scalar and adding matrices.  It might be easier to understand if we include an intermediate step:
$$
\begin{align}
\Phi(t) &= 
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \pmatrix{-2&0\\1&-1}t +  \pmatrix{4&0\\-3&1}\frac{t^2}{2} + \pmatrix{8&0\\-7&-1} \frac{t^3}{3!} + \cdots
\\ & = 
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \pmatrix{-2t&0\\t&-t} +  \pmatrix{2t^2&0\\-3t^2/2&t^2/2}+ \pmatrix{\frac 8{3!}t^3&0\\-\frac{7}{3!}t^3& -\frac{1}{3!}t^3}  + \cdots
\\ & = 
\pmatrix{1 - 2t + 2t^2 + \frac{8}{3!}t^3 + \cdots & 0\\
t - 3t^2/2 + -\frac{7}{3!}t^3 + \cdots & 1 - t + t^2/2 - \frac 1{3!}t^3 + \cdots}.
\end{align}
$$